# Jquery find table cell where value is X

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

I am trying to find a `<td>` where the value is 5. It is a calender so there will only be one 5 value.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === '5'
})
```

Comment: @welovedesign Why not? For this case there is no difference between == and ===.

Comment: The three `===` is to do explicit comparison, and disallow implicit comparison. Always use `===`, as it is very unstable to rely on implicit conversions JavaScript will do for you on the fly.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
var td = $("td:contains('5')");
```

***Edit:***
This will also select the td with `15` and `25`, if you want exact `5`, then use the `.filter` method as the other answer said.