# jquery find table cell with value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with id trends_table. I want the cell with the exact match of "Page Fans"

```
 $j("#trends_table td:contains('Page Fans')")
```

This gives me all cells that contain, how do I do equals? I have fiddled with a bunch of syntax but nothing I can find works.

I see this,  [Jquery find table cell where value is X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746846/jquery-find-table-cell-where-value-is-x) but dont see how I would do it for a given table, dont understand the context.

thanks
Joel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#trends_table td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Page Fans';
}).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Here is an example of what you try to accomplish.
http://jsfiddle.net/bQdpp/1/ .In this example I just turn the cells red, take care if more then 1 cell is returned then all the cells are turned red.

Answer (score 9):

Try using a filter. See below,

```
$j('#trends_table td').filter(function () {
  return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'Page Fans';
});
```